# Tablesorter clearing out table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using the tablesorter plugin and am attempting to make a function that clears the table of all of its data but I can't seem to get it to work. This is my current javascript.

JAVASCRIPT

```
var $table = $('#distributorTable');
$.tablesorter.clearTableBody( $table[0] );
$table.trigger('update');
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function sortName(){

var $table = $('#distributorTable');
$.tablesorter.clearTableBody( $table[0] );

var sortDirection = "";

if (document.getElementById('setSortDirection').value == ""){

    sortDirection = "asc";
    document.getElementById('setSortDirection').value = "asc";
}
else if (document.getElementById('setSortDirection').value == "asc"){

    document.getElementById('setSortDirection').value = "desc";
    sortDirection = "desc";
}
else if (document.getElementById('setSortDirection').value == "desc"){

    document.getElementById('setSortDirection').value = "asc";
    sortDirection = "asc";
}

var offset = document.getElementById('offset').value;

$.get("ajax-content.php", { offset: offset, sortDirection: sortDirection, sortType: "name"}, 

function(html) {

  $("#distributorTable").append(html);

  var resort = true;
  $("table").trigger("update", [resort]);

  document.getElementById('setSort').value = "name";

});

return false;
}
```

AJAX page

http://pastebin.com/b7T7ViAi

I used pastebin because trying to format the code on here was too annoying.

Comment: Could you post a bit more of your JavaScript/HTML and perhaps a demo snippet? My own small [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gfwccu07/) works fine with your functions.

Comment: Added some more of my code

Comment: You should use something like jsfiddle plunkr or jsbin, which can format and provide a demo

Answer (score 0):

I found that your code almost works, one small change and you have a working clear function:

```
function clearRows(tableClass) {
    var table = $(tableClass);
    $.tablesorter.clearTableBody(table);
    table.trigger('update');
}
```

It's important to call `update` after clearing the table body or everything will come back the next time you add any rows.